# addNumericRefinement OR with different operators

Tags: javascript, algolia

The Algolia search helper docs (https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-helper-js#filtering-results) shows how to create an ORed numeric refinement with the same operator using the following:

```
helper.addNumericRefinement('numericAttribute', '=', ['1', '2', '4'] );
```

But how do you add a further refinement that uses a different operator?

My tests show that adding:

```
helper.addNumericRefinement('numericAttribute', '>=', 10 );
```

Creates an ANDed refinement which returns nothing as numericAttribute cannot be 1 AND >10 simultaneously.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use the notations from the algolia API:

```
helper.setQueryParameter("numericFilters", "a>=3, b<5,(b = 2, b = 5)");
```

Just bear in mind that you won't be able to use the classic methods for doing numeric refinements anymore.

Comment: Thanks, seems to be working as intended. Do you know how to get the url to sync using this method?

Comment: Sigh. Can't even use the classic methods for doing numeric refinements within other components. Basically any default component :(